# Separate check box out put value to separate textbox

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<script>
var itemsAdded = Array();

function moveNumbers(text) { 
var i = itemsAdded.indexOf(text)
if ( i >= 0) { 
   itemsAdded.splice(i,1); 
} else {
   itemsAdded.push(text);
}
document.getElementById("list").value=itemsAdded.join("");

}

$(function() {
for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
console.log(i);
$("body").append("<input type='checkbox' id='list' name='list' value='"+ i +"' onclick='moveNumbers(this.value)'/> Checkbox"+ i +"<br/>");      
}
});
```

```
<legend>5x7</legend>
<input type="text" name="list" id="list"  style="width:800px; background:#B0D2D7">

<legend>Print size</legend>
<input style='width:20px; height:20px; background-color: #ff6633;'
type='checkbox' id='list' name='list' value='$file - 5x7,'
onclick='moveNumbers(this.value)'>5x7
```

Hi all, new at this stuff so here goes, I have this so far which all works fine. It displays check boxes next to images that are displayed on web page via a PHP script.
When checked it displays the file name and the image print size inside of a text box.

I tried to add more check boxes / text boxes with another print size say 6x8 and repeat the script with some changes. It sort of worked but not correctly. Any ideas would be great!
Cheers.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? why did you call append?

Comment: The web page displays multiple images. When a check box is checked it adds the file name and the print size. The more you check from the list the more it adds. It also keeps the check box out put value on to the next web page.

Comment: separate check box adds value to separate text box basically..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve but when wanting to get the value of checkboxes you can get their values simply for example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function check(id)
{
if ( document.getElementById(id).checked){
var vl=document.getElementById(id).value;
document.getElementById("txt1").value += vl;
}
}
</script>

</head>
<input type="checkbox" id='1' onClick='check(1)' value="5*7-">5*7
<input type="checkbox" id='2' onClick='check(2)' value="5*8-">5*8
<input type="textbox" id="txt1" name=one>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Nickparsa I'll have a play around with this and see how I go.